# Remove rows in table that have rows with missing values

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

How can I remove those rows in a table that have a missing element.

For a contrived example:

```
Table[{If[i == 1, Missing[NotApplicable], i], j}, {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 
   2}] // TableForm
```

Gives:

[image]

But I want is:

[image]

In the real example there is is more complex function that sometimes returns missing for some values, and I want those rows excluded.

Ideally, if the first element in the row is missing, the rest of the elements in the row would not be processed, but that is just a performance bonus.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried `DeleteMissing[expr, 1, Infinity]`? This should remove any elements at the first level that contain `Missing` at any depth. It's one of the syntax examples in the "Details" section of the docs for [`DeleteMissing`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteMissing.html).

Comment: Very handy. Is there a way to get this to work with a table? The table currently has headers that I want to keep

Comment: If by table you mean the output of `TableForm`, that won't work in all likelihood. in general `TableForm` is for output formatting only. Its output cannot be used for further computation.

Comment: Yes. So what is the right way to do what I am looking for? I am happy to convert it to a dataset or something else if that would be easier. So long as I have the headers (row and column) its not a big deal what it looks like exactly

Comment: A `Dataset` would probably be the most appropriate construct; a quick and dirty `Grid` might also work for formatting.

Comment: Did that and it worked.

Answer (score 7):

Try `Cases`.

```
tab = {{Missing[NotApplicable], 1},{2, 3},{4, 5}};
Cases[tab, Except[{___, Missing[___], ___}]]
(*{{2, 3}, {4, 5}}*)
```

The pattern `Except[{___, Missing[___], ___}]` matches anything that's not a list containing an element of head `Missing`.

Comment: I just realized, this is coming from a table with headers. Is there a way to do this either with the table generation, or get the headers to work with the new data (i.e. delete the headers that are no longer valid)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps simply this

```
 t=Table[{If[i == 1, Missing[NotApplicable], i], j}, {i, 1, 2}, {j, 
 1, 2}]
 Drop[t, 1, None] // TableForm
```

Answer (score 2):

```
expr = {{{{{Missing[NotApplicable]}}}, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}};
```

For versions 10.0+,  `DeleteMissing[expr, 1, Infinity]` gives the desired result as noted by MarcoB in the comments.

```
DeleteMissing[expr, 1, Infinity]
```

> {{2, 3}, {4, 5}}

For earlier versions you can use

```
Select[expr, FreeQ[#, _Missing] &] (* or *)
DeleteCases[expr, _?(Not[FreeQ[#, _Missing]] &)]
```

> {{2, 3}, {4, 5}}